# A bad use of RedirectPermanent

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I try actually to change my url => www.mysite.com to www.mysite.com/fr/ and i have to use my .htaccess for that.

So i changed my .htaccess from my root like that:

```
SetEnv SHORT_OPEN_TAGS 0
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv SESSION_AUTOSTART 0
SetEnv ZEND_OPTIMIZER 1
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
    RedirectPermanent / http://www.chat.com/fr/
</IfModule>
```

and i have my /web/.htaccess like that:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

and when i try to upload my site, i have this url : www.mysite.com/fr/fr/fr/fr/... and an error. Someone can help me ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules will indeed cause a redirect loop. Try this in root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/?$ /fr/ [L,R]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure to test this after clearing your browser cache.